# How can I fix "Error: Permission denied @ unlink_internal - .." when I try to brew cleanup

Tags: homebrew

How can I fix:

```
Error: Permission denied @ unlink_internal - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/.bin/detect-libc
```

when I try brew cleanup?

Answer (score 11):

This appears to be a permissions issue on your `/usr/local/lib/` directory. Perhaps you could grant the current user the necessary permissions and then try re-executing the `brew cleanup` command. Something along the lines of:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/lib
brew cleanup
```

Hopefully that helps!